# Type safety during assignment vs initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, type-safety

One of the stated advantages of initializer list syntax is that it improves type safety by prohibiting [narrowing conversions](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#note-182):

```
int x {7.9};   // error: narrowing
int y = 7.9;   // OK: y becomes 7. Hope for a compiler warning
```

However, AFAIK there is no way to enforce the same check in a subsequent assignment:

```
int z {7};
z = 7.9;  // allows narrowing, and no other syntax available
```

Why is type safety during initialization given greater attention by the language design than type safety during assignment? Is narrowing in assignments less likely to cause bugs and/or harder to detect?

Comment: between `int x{7.9}` and `int x = {7.9}` no diffrence

Comment: @21koizyd -- those are **both** initialization. In particular, the second one is **not** assignment. So, yes, trivially, no difference.

Comment: @PeteBecker of course you're right because e.g `std::atomic<int> a{5} // is good ` but `std::atomic<int> a = 5 // is wrong`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `x` is an `int` variable, then

```
x = 7.9;
```

must continue working in C++11 and later for the reason of backward compatibility. This is the case even if `x` was brace-initialized. A brace-initialized `int` variable has the same type as a non-brace-initialized `int` variable. If you passed `x` by reference to a function,

```
void f(int& r);
f(x);
```

then in the body of `f` there would be no way to "tell" whether the object had been brace-initialized, so the language cannot apply different rules to it.

You can prevent narrowing conversions yourself by doing this:

```
x = {7.9};  // error
```

You could also try to take advantage of the type system by creating an `int` "wrapper" type that disallowed narrowing assignments:

```
struct safe_int {
    template <class T> safe_int(T&& x) : value{std::forward<T>(x)} {}
    template <class T> safe_int& operator=(T&& x) {
        value = {std::forward<T>(x)}; return *this;
    }
    operator int() const { return value; }
    int value;
};
```

Unfortunately this class cannot be made to behave like an actual `int` object under all circumstances.

Comment: I wonder if it isn't better to always pass by value in the constructor because it is a primitive type and an `int` is cheap to pass in a register for example instead of a reference.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I think it doesn't matter because the compiler will optimize it :P

Comment: Actually until your example, I didn't realize I can use initializer list outside of the initialization with the same effect of disabling narrowing conversions: `x = {7.9}` is treated the same as `int x {7.9}` or `int x = {7.9}`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is type safety during initialization given greater attention by
>   the language design than type safety during assignment?

No that's not the reason here, it's the list initialization that's giving you the error, for example, this would error too:

```
int x = {7.8};
```

And that is because narrowing is not allowed in list initialization, as per [dcl.init]:

> If the initializer-clause is an expression and a narrowing conversion
>   is required to convert the expression, the program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

`{}` prevent convertion type e.g `double` to `int`
but

`()` can do this, only can display warning about conversion

you can to write like this

`int z(7.9) // == 7`

you can use brackets when you are sure, that in class don't exist constructor with `std::initializer_list`, because he would be execute or you can `delete` that constructor.